# Eliminate duplicates, change label with scala.xml.transform.RuleTransformer

Tags: xml, scala

I have the following XML:

```
<tree>
  <leaf id="1"/>
  <leaf id="1"/>
</tree>
```

What I would like to do is get rid of the duplicate `<leaf/>`s (in the entire XML document), and replace them with a single `<new-leaf/>` like so:

```
<tree>
  <new-leaf id="1"/>
</tree>
```

I've written the following `RewriteRule`, which I believe should have accomplished this (pardon the statefulness):

```
import scala.xml._
import scala.xml.transform._

class UniqueLeaves extends RewriteRule {

  var leafIds = Set.empty[String]

  override def transform(node: Node): Seq[Node] = node match {
    case e: Elem if ((e.label == "leaf") && !leafIds.contains((e \\ "@id").text)) => {
      leafIds += (e \\ "@id").text
      <new-leaf id={(e \\ "@id")} />
    }
    case e: Elem if (e.label == "leaf") => Seq.empty
    case _ => node
  }

}
```

Unfortunately, using a `RuleTransformer` gives me the following:

```
scala> val tree = <tree><leaf id="1"/><leaf id="1"/></tree>
scala> println(new RuleTransformer(new UniqueLeaves).transform(tree))
<tree/>
```

I'm assuming that this is because [`RuleTransformer` calls `transform` on the `RewriteRule` multiple times](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3689), and is using the non-first call to output the `<new-leaf>` node, which returns an empty `Seq` in my match.

Would appreciate any tips on making this work (and be non-stateful).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone with a similar question, I've found the following solution:

```
def removeDuplicates(tree: Node): Node = {
  var ids = Set.empty[String]
  def recurse(node: Node): Seq[Node] = node match {
    case e: Elem if (e.label == "leaf") => {
      val id = (e \\ "@id").text
      ids.contains(id) match {
        case true => Seq.empty
        case _ => {
          ids = ids + id
          <new-leaf id={id}/>
        }
      }
    }
    case e: Elem => e.copy(child = e.nonEmptyChildren.map(recurse(_).headOption).flatten)
    case _ => node
  }
  recurse(tree).head
}
```

This works because it handles node traversal manually, not using `RuleTransformer#transform`, and therefore does not iterate over the same node more than once (although it's still stateful, unfortunately).